# Cannot post data to woocommerce api

Tags: woocommerce, axios, woocommerce-rest-api

This seems to be a common problem and I have tried a few of the solutions but still have the issue. I am sending a post request from Axios and getting a 401 error when trying to create an order. The user does not need to be logged in to place the order. I have generated my API keys in WooCommerce a few times yet still no joy.The error I get back is `woocommerce_rest_cannot_create`

It works over https but not over http. The docs mention some ridiculously complicated solution using oauth with not much in terms of how to do it.

```
   const data = {
      payment_method: "bacs",
      payment_method_title: "Direct Bank Transfer",
      set_paid: true,
      billing: {
        first_name: "Joe",
        last_name: "Soap",
        address_1: "969 Market",
        address_2: "",
        city: "San Francisco",
        state: "CA",
        postcode: "94103",
        country: "US",
        email: "joe@gmail.com",
        phone: "(555) 555-5555",
      },
      shipping: {
        first_name: "Joe",
        last_name: "Soap",
        address_1: "969 Market",
        address_2: "",
        city: "San Francisco",
        state: "CA",
        postcode: "94103",
        country: "US",
      },
      line_items: [
        {
          product_id: 130,
          quantity: 2,
        },
        {
          product_id: 128,
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      shipping_lines: [
        {
          method_id: "flat_rate",
          method_title: "Flat Rate",
          total: "10.00",
        },
      ],
    };

    const response = await axios.post(
      `http://localhost:8888/myapi/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=ck_xxxxxxxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxxxxxx`,
      data
    );
    console.log(response);
```

Comment: If it works over https, then you're all set, no? What question do you still have?

Comment: @jmargolisvt I want to get it to work over http on my localhost for testing before working on a live server.